# How Nomad knows internally about the allocation status of job (Running, Failed, Queued, Starting, Complete, Lost)?

Tags: nomad, hashicorp

[Allocation status Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpteA.png)

Hi team,
we can see about the allocation status of a job in nomad UI / command line.
but how nomad finds whether a job is running or it failed or it completed ?
Basically want to know how nomad figure out about allocation status.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the agent running on each node in the cluster will report it back to the nomad servers.

How the agent knows?

Most certainly there's a watch loop in agent's code for monitoring each allocation running on the node.